# How can I get via jQuery which button of a table was clicked and get all the data from that row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, frontend

Here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-stripped table-bordered table-hover centerAll" cellpadding="10">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Nombre</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Descripción Corta</th>
                        <th>Precio</th>
                        <th>Imagen</th>
                        <th>Descuento</th>
                        <th>Instrucciones de Uso</th>
                        <th>Ingrediente</th>
                        <th>Meta</th>
                        <th>Categoria</th>
                        <th>Marca</th>
                        <th>Reorden</th>
                        <th>Actualizar</th>
                        <th>Eliminar</th>
                        <th>Variaciones de Producto</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="tableClick">
                        <tr>
                            <td><span id='nombre'>Prod 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcion'>Esta es una descripcion 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcionCorta'>Descripcion corta 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='precio'>$1500</span></td>
                            <td><span id='imagen'>Link 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descuento'>25%</span></td>
                            <td><span id='instruccionesUso'>Se usa asi 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='ingrediente'>ingrediente 1, ingrediente 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='meta'>meta 1, meta 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='categoria'>Cat 1, cat 2, cat 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='marca'>marca 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='reorden'>reorden 1</span></td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="updateProducto" value="Actualizar"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteProducto" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            <td><a href="updateDeleteVariaciones.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" style="width: 150px !important" role="button" class="btn btn-info">Variaciones de producto</a></td>
                        </tr>

                         <tr>
                            <td><span id='nombre'>Prod 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcion'>Esta es una descripcion 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcionCorta'>Descripcion corta 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='precio'>$1500</span></td>
                            <td><span id='imagen'>Link 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descuento'>25%</span></td>
                            <td><span id='instruccionesUso'>Se usa asi 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='ingrediente'>ingrediente 1, ingrediente 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='meta'>meta 1, meta 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='categoria'>Cat 1, cat 2, cat 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='marca'>marca 1</span></td>
                            <td><span id='reorden'>reorden 1</span></td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="updateProducto" value="Actualizar"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteProducto" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            <td><a href="updateDeleteVariaciones.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" style="width: 150px !important" role="button" class="btn btn-info">Variaciones de producto</a></td>
                        </tr>

                          <tr>
                            <td><span id='nombre'>Prod 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcion'>Esta es una descripcion 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcionCorta'>Descripcion corta 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='precio'>$1000</span></td>
                            <td><span id='imagen'>Link 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descuento'>35%</span></td>
                            <td><span id='instruccionesUso'>Se usa asi 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='ingrediente'>ingrediente 3, ingrediente 4</span></td>
                            <td><span id='meta'>meta 3, meta 4</span></td>
                            <td><span id='categoria'>Cat 4, cat 5, cat 6</span></td>
                            <td><span id='marca'>marca 2</span></td>
                            <td><span id='reorden'>reorden 2</span></td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="updateProducto" value="Actualizar"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteProducto" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            <td><a href="updateDeleteVariaciones.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" style="width: 150px !important" role="button" class="btn btn-info">Variaciones de producto</a></td>
                        </tr>

                           <tr>
                            <td><span id='nombre'>Prod 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcion'>Esta es una descripcion 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descripcionCorta'>Descripcion corta 4</span></td>
                            <td><span id='precio'>$2500</span></td>
                            <td><span id='imagen'>Link 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='descuento'>45%</span></td>
                            <td><span id='instruccionesUso'>Se usa asi 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='ingrediente'>ingrediente 5, ingrediente 6</span></td>
                            <td><span id='meta'>meta 5, meta 6</span></td>
                            <td><span id='categoria'>Cat 7, cat 8, cat 9</span></td>
                            <td><span id='marca'>marca 3</span></td>
                            <td><span id='reorden'>reorden 3</span></td>
                            <td><input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="updateProducto" value="Actualizar"></td>
                            <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="deleteProducto" value="Eliminar"></td>
                            <td><a href="updateDeleteVariaciones.php?id=<?php echo $id; ?>" style="width: 150px !important" role="button" class="btn btn-info">Variaciones de producto</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

And this is the javascript I'm trying to use:

```
function handleEvent(e) {
                    var something = this.closest('tr').find('td:eq(1)').text();
                    console.log(something);
                }
                $('#tableClick').on('click', function(){
                    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
                    for (var row in rows) {
                        row.addEventListener('click', handleEvent);
                    } 
                });
```

I have no idea how else I can do it, and the error I get on the browser is Object 0 has no method `addEventListener`.. Why is that happening? Is it also the right way of getting to know which button was clicked? and how can I get each of the `<span>`'s text value into a variable? I have ran out of ideas on how to get this done.

Comment: you are repeating same ID for more than one DOM....which is incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#tableClick').on('click', '.btn-info', function () {
    var currentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
    //do something with values in td's
    var firstTDValue = currentRow.find("td").eq(0).children("span").text();
    var secondTDValue = currentRow.find("td").eq(1).children("span").text();
    //and so on
});
```

Edit: But like @Dinesh suggested in the comment, you should use `class` instead of `id` if you're going to have the same being repeated.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, how could I access the values of the td's?

Comment: Thanks for that, updated them accordingly. Changed to class instead of ID.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up the parent element, and then find the parent row from the clicked button. Take a look at this example I made: http://jsfiddle.net/TLgqf/

```
$(function() {
$('.btn').on('click', function(){
var button = $(this);
var parentTd = button.parent('td');
var parentTr = parentTd.parent('tr');
var nombre = parentTr.find('td #nombre').html();

alert(nombre);
```

});
});